# Align div elements at the next line

Tags: html, css

What I need is a grid of pictures. The first line of four pictures is looking great. But I can't find the solution to arrange the second line. Well, I know I can use the ul li along with the display: inline-block and vertical-align: text-top; but I want the div solution.
Thank You.

```css
.partners
{
margin: 77px auto 0 auto;
overflow: auto;
text-align: center;
width: 940px;
}
.partners__h2
{
color: #333;
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-bottom: 32px;
text-align: center;
}
.partner__pic__wrap
{
height: 120px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
width: 120px;
}
.partner__icon
{
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
border: 4px solid #fff;
border-radius: 50%;
bottom: -5px;
height: 32px;
position: absolute;
right: -4px;
width: 32px;
z-index: 1;
}
.partner__pic__hover:hover
{
filter: alpha(opacity=70);
opacity: 0.7;
}
.partner__wrap
{
bottom: 0;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}
.partner__name
{
color: #333;
display: block;
float: left;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
}
.partner__description
{
color: #666;
float: left;
font-family: Roboto;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 300;
margin-top: 10px;
text-align: center;
}
.partner__1
{
float: left;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
width: 221px;
}
.partner__1__icon
{
background-color: #ff4e50;
background-image: url('http://www.q-park.co.uk/DesktopModules/QPark.AdvancedPFL/image.aspx?ServiceID=49');
}
.partner__1__pic
{
background-image: url('http://cdn.bmwblog.com/wp-content/uploads/BMW-M235i-racing-car-las-vegas-02-120x120.jpg');
background-position: center;
border-radius: 50%;
float: left;
height: 120px;
moz-border-radius: 50%;
webkit-border-radius: 50%;
width: 120px;
}
.partner__2
{
float: left;
height: 100%;
margin-left: 19px;
position: relative;
width: 221px;
}
.partner__2__icon
{
background-color: #1cd7ad;
background-image: url('http://www.q-park.co.uk/DesktopModules/QPark.AdvancedPFL/image.aspx?ServiceID=49');
}
.partner__2__pic
{
background-image: url('http://cdn.bmwblog.com/wp-content/uploads/BMW-M235i-racing-car-las-vegas-02-120x120.jpg');
background-position: center top;
border-radius: 50%;
float: left;
height: 120px;
moz-border-radius: 50%;
webkit-border-radius: 50%;
width: 120px;
}
.partner__3
{
float: left;
height: 100%;
margin-left: 19px;
position: relative;
width: 221px;
}
.partner__3__icon
{
background-color: #ffa507;
background-image: url('http://www.q-park.co.uk/DesktopModules/QPark.AdvancedPFL/image.aspx?ServiceID=49');
}
.partner__3__pic
{
background-image: url('http://cdn.bmwblog.com/wp-content/uploads/BMW-M235i-racing-car-las-vegas-02-120x120.jpg');
background-position: center top;
border-radius: 50%;
float: left;
height: 120px;
moz-border-radius: 50%;
webkit-border-radius: 50%;
width: 120px;
}
.partner__4
{
float: left;
height: 100%;
margin-left: 20px;
position: relative;
width: 219px;
}
.partner__4__icon
{
background-color: #4e73db;
background-image: url('http://www.q-park.co.uk/DesktopModules/QPark.AdvancedPFL/image.aspx?ServiceID=49');
}
.partner__4__pic
{
background-image: url('http://cdn.bmwblog.com/wp-content/uploads/BMW-M235i-racing-car-las-vegas-02-120x120.jpg');
background-position: center top;
border-radius: 50%;
float: left;
height: 120px;
moz-border-radius: 50%;
webkit-border-radius: 50%;
width: 120px;
}
.partner__5, .partner__6, .partner__7, .partner__8
{
float: left;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
width: 221px;
}
```

```html
<div class="partners">
<div class="partners__container">
    <h2 class="partners__h2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer</h2>
    <div class="partner__1">
        <div class="partner__pic__wrap">
            <div class="partner__1__icon partner__icon"></div>
            <a class="partner__1__pic partner__pic__hover" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="partner__wrap">
            <h4 class="partner__name">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <p class="partner__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="partner__2">
        <div class="partner__pic__wrap">
            <div class="partner__2__icon partner__icon"></div>
            <a class="partner__2__pic partner__pic__hover" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="partner__wrap">
            <h4 class="partner__name">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <p class="partner__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="partner__3">
        <div class="partner__pic__wrap">
            <div class="partner__3__icon partner__icon"></div>
            <a class="partner__3__pic partner__pic__hover" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="partner_wrap">
            <h4 class="partner__name">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <p class="partner__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="partner__4">
        <div class="partner__pic__wrap">
            <div class="partner__4__icon partner__icon"></div>
            <a class="partner__4__pic partner__pic__hover" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="partner_wrap">
            <h4 class="partner__name">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <p class="partner__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="partner__5">
        <div class="partner__pic__wrap">
            <div class="partner__4__icon partner__icon"></div>
            <a class="partner__4__pic partner__pic__hover" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="partner_wrap">
            <h4 class="partner__name">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <p class="partner__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="partner__6">
        <div class="partner__pic__wrap">
            <div class="partner__4__icon partner__icon"></div>
            <a class="partner__4__pic partner__pic__hover" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="partner_wrap">
            <h4 class="partner__name">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <p class="partner__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="partner__7">
        <div class="partner__pic__wrap">
            <div class="partner__4__icon partner__icon"></div>
            <a class="partner__4__pic partner__pic__hover" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="partner_wrap">
            <h4 class="partner__name">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <p class="partner__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="partner__8">
        <div class="partner__pic__wrap">
            <div class="partner__4__icon partner__icon"></div>
            <a class="partner__4__pic partner__pic__hover" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="partner_wrap">
            <h4 class="partner__name">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <p class="partner__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you try flexbox? it´s ideal for this kind of structure.

Comment: No, but thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**CSS**

```
.partners__container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.partners__container > div {
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 20%;
    flex: 1 0 20%;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/dxvL95yo/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to give fixed height instead of 100% for all 8 blocks.

```
.partner__1, .partner__2, .partner__3, .partner__4, .partner__5, .partner__6, .partner__7, .partner__8 {
    height: 220px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I knew it. But is there another way?

Comment: otherwise you can try for flexbox concept, see Luis's answer above

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
.partners__container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.partners__container > div {
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 20%;
    flex: 1 0 20%;
}
.partners {
    width: 940px;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 77px auto 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
.partners__h2 {
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
}
.partner__pic__wrap {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.partner__icon {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;
    right: -4px;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
}
.partner__pic__hover:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
}
.partner__wrap {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
.partner__name {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.partner__description {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.partner__1 {
    float:left;
    width:221px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.partner__1__icon {
    background-image: url('http://www.q-park.co.uk/DesktopModules/QPark.AdvancedPFL/image.aspx?ServiceID=49');
    background-color: #ff4e50;
}
.partner__1__pic {
    background-image: url('http://cdn.bmwblog.com/wp-content/uploads/BMW-M235i-racing-car-las-vegas-02-120x120.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.partner__2 {
    float:left;
    width:221px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 19px;
    position: relative;
}
.partner__2__icon {
    background-image: url('http://www.q-park.co.uk/DesktopModules/QPark.AdvancedPFL/image.aspx?ServiceID=49');
    background-color: #1cd7ad;
}
.partner__2__pic {
    background-image: url('http://cdn.bmwblog.com/wp-content/uploads/BMW-M235i-racing-car-las-vegas-02-120x120.jpg');
    background-position: center top;
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.partner__3 {
    float:left;
    width:221px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 19px;
    position: relative;
}
.partner__3__icon {
    background-image: url('http://www.q-park.co.uk/DesktopModules/QPark.AdvancedPFL/image.aspx?ServiceID=49');
    background-color: #ffa507;
}
.partner__3__pic {
    background-image: url('http://cdn.bmwblog.com/wp-content/uploads/BMW-M235i-racing-car-las-vegas-02-120x120.jpg');
    background-position: center top;
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.partner__4 {
    float:left;
    width:219px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.partner__4__icon {
    background-image: url('http://www.q-park.co.uk/DesktopModules/QPark.AdvancedPFL/image.aspx?ServiceID=49');
    background-color: #4e73db;
}
.partner__4__pic {
    background-image: url('http://cdn.bmwblog.com/wp-content/uploads/BMW-M235i-racing-car-las-vegas-02-120x120.jpg');
    background-position: center top;
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.partner__5, .partner__6, .partner__7, .partner__8 {
    float:left;
    width:221px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/L313wpu2/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.partners
{
 margin: 77px auto 0 auto;
 overflow: auto;
 text-align: center;
 width: 940px;
}
.partners__h2
{
 color: #333;
    font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-bottom: 32px;
 text-align: center;
}
.partner__pic__wrap
{
 height: 120px;
    margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 width: 120px;
}
.partner__icon
{
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 border: 4px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 50%;
 bottom: -5px;
 height: 32px;
 position: absolute;
 right: -4px;
 width: 32px;
 z-index: 1;
}
.partner__pic__hover:hover
{
 filter: alpha(opacity=70);
 opacity: 0.7;
}
.partner__wrap
{
 bottom: 0;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}
.partner__name
{
 color: #333;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     width: 100%;
}
.partner__description
{
 color: #666;
 float: left;
 font-family: Roboto;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 300;
 margin-top: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}
.partner
{
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
 margin-left:10px;
 width: 221px;     
}
.partner__1__icon
{
 background-color: #ff4e50;
 background-image: url('http://www.q-park.co.uk/DesktopModules/QPark.AdvancedPFL/image.aspx?ServiceID=49');
}
.partner__1__pic
{
     background-image: url('http://cdn.bmwblog.com/wp-content/uploads/BMW-M235i-racing-car-las-vegas-02-120x120.jpg');
     background-position: center;
 border-radius: 50%;
 float: left;
     height: 120px;
 moz-border-radius: 50%;
 webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 width: 120px;
}

.partner__2__icon
{
 background-color: #1cd7ad;
 background-image: url('http://www.q-park.co.uk/DesktopModules/QPark.AdvancedPFL/image.aspx?ServiceID=49');
}
.partner__2__pic
{
background-image: url('http://cdn.bmwblog.com/wp-content/uploads/BMW-M235i-racing-car-las-vegas-02-120x120.jpg');
background-position: center top;
border-radius: 50%;
float: left;
height: 120px;
moz-border-radius: 50%;
webkit-border-radius: 50%;
width: 120px;
}
   
.partner__3__icon
{
background-color: #ffa507;
background-image: url('http://www.q-park.co.uk/DesktopModules/QPark.AdvancedPFL/image.aspx?ServiceID=49');
}
.partner__3__pic
{
background-image: url('http://cdn.bmwblog.com/wp-content/uploads/BMW-M235i-racing-car-las-vegas-02-120x120.jpg');
background-position: center top;
border-radius: 50%;
float: left;
height: 120px;
moz-border-radius: 50%;
webkit-border-radius: 50%;
width: 120px;
}
   
.partner__4__icon
{
background-color: #4e73db;
background-image: url('http://www.q-park.co.uk/DesktopModules/QPark.AdvancedPFL/image.aspx?ServiceID=49');
}
.partner__4__pic
{
background-image: url('http://cdn.bmwblog.com/wp-content/uploads/BMW-M235i-racing-car-las-vegas-02-120x120.jpg');
background-position: center top;
border-radius: 50%;
float: left;
height: 120px;
moz-border-radius: 50%;
webkit-border-radius: 50%;
width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="partners">
<div class="partners__container">
    <h2 class="partners__h2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer</h2>
    <div class="partner">
        <div class="partner__pic__wrap">
            <div class="partner__1__icon partner__icon"></div>
            <a class="partner__1__pic partner__pic__hover" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="partner__wrap">
            <h4 class="partner__name">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <p class="partner__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="partner">
        <div class="partner__pic__wrap">
            <div class="partner__2__icon partner__icon"></div>
            <a class="partner__2__pic partner__pic__hover" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="partner__wrap">
            <h4 class="partner__name">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <p class="partner__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="partner">
        <div class="partner__pic__wrap">
            <div class="partner__3__icon partner__icon"></div>
            <a class="partner__3__pic partner__pic__hover" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="partner_wrap">
            <h4 class="partner__name">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <p class="partner__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="partner">
        <div class="partner__pic__wrap">
            <div class="partner__4__icon partner__icon"></div>
            <a class="partner__4__pic partner__pic__hover" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="partner_wrap">
            <h4 class="partner__name">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <p class="partner__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="partner">
        <div class="partner__pic__wrap">
            <div class="partner__4__icon partner__icon"></div>
            <a class="partner__4__pic partner__pic__hover" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="partner_wrap">
            <h4 class="partner__name">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <p class="partner__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="partner">
        <div class="partner__pic__wrap">
            <div class="partner__4__icon partner__icon"></div>
            <a class="partner__4__pic partner__pic__hover" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="partner_wrap">
            <h4 class="partner__name">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <p class="partner__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="partner">
        <div class="partner__pic__wrap">
            <div class="partner__4__icon partner__icon"></div>
            <a class="partner__4__pic partner__pic__hover" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="partner_wrap">
            <h4 class="partner__name">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <p class="partner__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="partner">
        <div class="partner__pic__wrap">
            <div class="partner__4__icon partner__icon"></div>
            <a class="partner__4__pic partner__pic__hover" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="partner_wrap">
            <h4 class="partner__name">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <p class="partner__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Check with above code once....

Comment: Why is the fourth picture in the second row not lined up with the other three?